# nvcc error : 'cicc' died with status 0xC0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION) when building tensorflow with bazel

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, nvcc

I am trying to build Tensorflow 1.14.0 dll. I am using bazel 0.24.1 to do it. I also use cuDNN 7.1.4 and CUDA 9.0.I want it to use Visual C++ Build Tools 2015, but when running bazel to build dll:

```
bazel build --config=cuda tensorflow:tensorflow.dll,
```

by default in LIB and INCLUDE variables path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023 is set. I then get bunch of errors like *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xutility(796): error: expression must have a constant value*. Build failes with error: *nvcc error   : 'cicc' died with status 0xC0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION)*.

I tried to set:

```
set BAZEL_VS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
set BAZEL_VC=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC
```

but error still occurs. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I finally got a solution. You can force correct paths by setting following environment variables:

CPU_COMPILER = ('C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe')
GCC_HOST_COMPILER_PATH = ('C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe')

just before running

```
bazel build --config=cuda tensorflow:tensorflow.dll
```

in commandline. It's best to do it in Powershell, as there is a problem with spaces/apostrophes in paths when using Windows commandline.